# secure AWS ES kibana through java proxy

Tags: java, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, kibana

I am doing the a POC with a spring application, through which I am trying to secure an AWS kibana through proxy. I want to allow only my logged in users to be able to access my Kibana.

So I have set my IAM to ip only and I am able run my ES queries without issue. Now I built a class using RESTTemplate class wherein I copied some of the required headers and pushed the request to kibana.

I am able to now load kibana for a logged in user. But I am not able to run any queries from the dev tools and or display any of the dashboards.

I have an index datacuts.

When I run the query

> GET datacuts/datacuts/_search

I get an index not found error. But at the same time if just say

> GET datacuts

I can see the mapping details of my index. Not sure what is happening here.

Here is the proxy code that I written

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://my-es-server"+restOfTheUrl);
            headers.add("content-type", request.getContentType());
            headers.add("kbn-version", "5.5.2");
            HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = (body==null)?new HttpEntity<>(headers):
                new HttpEntity<String>(body,headers);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
            ResponseEntity<String> resp = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toString(), HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod()), httpEntity, String.class);
switch(resp.getHeaders().getContentType().getType()) {
            case "text" :
                String responseBody = resp.getBody().toString();
                logger.debug("index count" + responseBody.indexOf("/_plugin/kibana"));
                responseBody = responseBody.replaceAll("_plugin/kibana","myApp/_plugin/kibana");
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(responseBody.toString(), resp.getHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            return resp;
```

The requests that are failing are the

proxy call _plugin/kibana/api/console/proxy?path=datacuts%2Fdatacuts%2F_search&method=GET where in i get the response there is not index by the name datacuts.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the right headers and a check on content type solved the problems for me.

I added the below code to my existing code

```
            headers.add(accessCtrl, url_to_host);
            headers.add(connect, keepAlive);
            headers.add(proxyConn, keepAlive);
            headers.add(contentType, request.getContentType());
            headers.add(kbn, kbnVerion);
            headers.add(cluster , cluster_key);
            request.setAttribute(presigned, false);
            headers.add(host, host);

            body=(body!=null && !body.equals(FieldNameConstant.BLANK) && "application/x-ndjson".equals(request.getContentType()))?body+"/n":body;
```

This solved my problem. Now I could implement a full kibana java proxy with spring!